# VideoCapture isOpened() always false with C++ OpenCV + QT + Android

Tags: android, c++, qt, opencv

I would like to be able to use c++ opencv 3.0 with QT 5.7 on an android 5.0 device.

The problem is related to the cv::VideoCapture open function. 
mCamera.isOpened() always return false.

Does android opencv build allow us to use the camera ? Is there anything special i could do ?

I read many post about android opencv and some times people said it's not possible to use it.

I've tried CV_CAP_ANDROID_FRONT, CV_CAP_ANDROID, CV_CAP_ANDROID_BACK, 0, 1.

This is the main.cpp:

```
cv::Mat inframe = cv::Mat();
cv::VideoCapture mCamera;
mCamera.open(CV_CAP_ANDROID_FRONT);
mCamera.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 400);
mCamera.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 300);

qDebug() << mCamera.isOpened();
while (mCamera.isOpened()) {
    bool grab = mCamera.grab();
    if (grab) {
        mCamera.retrieve(inframe, CV_CAP_ANDROID_FRONT);
    } else {
        cout << "--->Cannot grab a frame from camera." << endl;;
    }
}
mCamera.release();
```

Here is my .pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += "$$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/opencv3Android/sdk/native/jni/include"
android {
    LIBS += \
        -L"$$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/opencv3Android/sdk/native/3rdparty/libs/armeabi-v7a"\
        -L"$$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/opencv3Android/sdk/native/libs/armeabi-v7a"\
        -llibtiff\
        -llibjpeg\
        -llibjasper\
        -llibpng\
        -lIlmImf\
        -ltbb\
        -lopencv_core\
        -lopencv_flann\
        -lopencv_imgproc\
        -lopencv_highgui\
        -lopencv_features2d\
        -lopencv_calib3d\
        -lopencv_ml\
        -lopencv_objdetect\
        -lopencv_video\
        -lopencv_photo\
        -lopencv_java3\
        -lopencv_stitching\
        -lopencv_superres\
        -lopencv_videostab

    ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR=$$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/android
    ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR = $$PWD/android-sources

}

contains(ANDROID_TARGET_ARCH,armeabi-v7a) {
    ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS = \
        $$PWD/opencv3Android/sdk/native/libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_java3.so
}

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/opencv3Android/sdk/native/3rdparty/libs/armeabi-v7a/release/ -ltegra_hal
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/opencv3Android/sdk/native/3rdparty/libs/armeabi-v7a/debug/ -ltegra_hal
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/opencv3Android/sdk/native/3rdparty/libs/armeabi-v7a/ -ltegra_hal

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/opencv3Android/sdk/native/3rdparty/libs/armeabi-v7a
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/opencv3Android/sdk/native/3rdparty/libs/armeabi-v7a

win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/opencv3Android/sdk/native/3rdparty/libs/armeabi-v7a/release/libtegra_hal.a
else:win32-g++:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/opencv3Android/sdk/native/3rdparty/libs/armeabi-v7a/debug/libtegra_hal.a
else:win32:!win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/opencv3Android/sdk/native/3rdparty/libs/armeabi-v7a/release/tegra_hal.lib
else:win32:!win32-g++:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/opencv3Android/sdk/native/3rdparty/libs/armeabi-v7a/debug/tegra_hal.lib
else:unix: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/opencv3Android/sdk/native/3rdparty/libs/armeabi-v7a/libtegra_hal.a

DISTFILES += \
    android-sources/AndroidManifest.xml
```

I also added permission to my manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I have the same problem atm :/

Comment: Sorry but i didn´t find any solution for this problem. I´ve read than using opencv camera under android is not a good idea. It depends of hardware + android version.

I did my project using android camera, fetch image, then use it with opencv

Comment: Oh i see. Could you tell me a few keyword to search for that solution?
Im not a native android dev so it definitely would take a bit longer if i would search on my own :)

Comment: Edit: I mean the solution with using the android cam and fetching the image from there. Is that possible in a native android (c++) project?